# Шифрование в java и javascript

Tags: javascript, java

Второй день не могу разобратся. 
У меня есть кот на ява который шифрует строку AES ключем. 
Пытаюсь написать веб приложение на ява скрипте которое выполнило тоже самое шифрование и выдало точно такой же результат.

```
   String s = "qwerty";
             IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec("1234567891234567".getBytes("UTF-8"));
            //генирируем случайный АЕС ключ
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

            //  KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            //kgen.init(256);
            //SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey();
            byte[] key = ("ytrewq").getBytes("UTF-8");
            // MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            // key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); // use only first 128 bit
            SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES");

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,secretKey);

            byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(s.getBytes());
            String loadCriptLogin = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bytes, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
            System.out.println(loadCriptLogin);
```

Может кто то сталкивался с такой проблемой, подскажите код js

Comment: Если твой **кот** умеет шифровать, то тебе надо с ним на научные выставки ездить. А вообще коту для шифрования по AES можно воспользоваться [js-библиотекой](https://github.com/ricmoo/aes-js)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Разный результат шифрования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/941268/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82-%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)