# Разный результат шифрования

Tags: javascript, java

Шифрую строку в java  и javascript. Использую одинаковые настройки, ключ, вектор, метод и т.д.

```
String s = "qwerty";
             IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec("1234567891234567".getBytes("UTF-8"));
            //генирируем случайный АЕС ключ
            Cipher cipher = (Cipher) Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/PKCS7Padding");

            //  KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            //kgen.init(256);
            //SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey();

            byte[] key = ("ytrewq").getBytes();
            //key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); // use only first 128 bit


            SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES");

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,secretKey,iv);

            byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(s.getBytes());
            String loadCriptLogin = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bytes, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
            System.out.println(loadCriptLogin);
```

код яваскрипт

```
var text = "qwerty"; 
var Key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("ytrewq"); 
var IV = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("1234567891234567"); 
var encryptedText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, Key, {iv: IV, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CFB, padding:  CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7});
```

Но на выходе получаю разные зашифрованые строки, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А вы уверены, что настройки в JS правильные ? Вот тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258047/java-default-crypto-aes-behavior говорят то java по умолчанию для AES использует ECB и Pkcs5

Comment: ну я же вроде как установил  AES/CFB/PKCS7Padding  , или надо как то подругому указывать?

Comment: Вот я и спрашиваю, вы уверены, что java у вас использует именно CFB/PKCS7, а не ECB/PKCS5 как написано по той ссылке ?

Comment: а как это можно проверить?

Comment: попробовав другие режимы. Хотя для начала стоило бы проверить на 128 битном блоке. Если результат на нем одинаков, значит дело точно в режимах. Если все равно разный - в чем то другом. Если понимаем что разница в этих настройках то пробуем меньше 128 бит, если результат различен - padding не правильный. Подбираем padding. Когда подобрали пробуем более 128 бит - отличаются, значит режим сцепки не тот

Comment: И ничего что вы в java строку выводите в base64. а в JS только до сырых данных доходите ? смотрели бы лучше в шестнадцетиричном виде

Comment: VphDc2abyvGb9AZ7cV5vsg== так выглядит строка в яваскрипте  lbT9Goiuwl1DpOrywEztlQ== а так в ява, думаю base64 тут как раз уместен. Изменение pading 7 на 5 ничего не даст https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232705/encrypt-text-to-aes-cbc-pkcs7padding . Я заметил, что если установить mode на ECB в java, перестает шифровать. А так, уже все попробовал, ничего не дало результатов

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Шифрование в java и javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/941254/204271)

Comment: А вот `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse` что по вашему делает ? Судя по названию она разбирает шестнадцеричную строку. И в примерах в интернете ей то же передают шестнадцеричные строки. А вы произвольные символы даете ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем кто откликнулся. В вопросе разобрался. Вот java и js код, может кому то поможет.

```
 <script src="crypto-js.js"></script>


<script>

//var key = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
       // var iv= CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('ytrewqqwerty1234');
var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('1234567891234567');
        var message = "qwerty";
        var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, key, { iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7  });

        var cipherData = iv.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)+":"+encrypted+":"+key.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
        console.log(cipherData);
</script>
```

ява код

```
  String ivstr = "MTIzNDU2Nzg5MTIzNDU2Nw=="; // вектор в бэйсе
            String s = "qwerty"; //строка которую шифруем
            String keyString = "eXRyZXdxcXdlcnR5MTIzNA=="; // ключ в бэйсе
            byte[] ivS = Base64.decode(ivstr, Base64.DEFAULT);
            byte[] keyB = Base64.decode(keyString, Base64.DEFAULT);
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivS);
            Key k = new SecretKeySpec(keyB, "AES");


        Cipher cipher = null;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k,iv);

            byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            String loadCriptLogin = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
            System.out.println(loadCriptLogin);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```